# Saving hex data to file in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, hex, fs

Say I've got a string

```js
"020000009B020000C0060000"
```

and I want to turn it into a string such that if it was saved as a file and opened it in a hex editor it would display the same hex as I put in.
How do I do this?
I've never had to use buffers or anything, but in trying to do this I've seemingly had to, and I don't really know what I'm doing.

(or whether I should be using buffers at all- I've been searching for hours and all I can find are answers that use buffers so I've just taken their examples and yet nothing is working)

I turned the hex string into a buffer

```js
function hexToBuffer(hex) {
  let typedArray = new Uint8Array(hex.match(/[\da-f]{2}/gi).map(function (h) {
    return parseInt(h, 16)
  }))
  return typedArray
}
```

and this seemed to work because logging `hexToBuffer("020000009B020000C0060000").buffer` what it returns gave me this:

```
ArrayBuffer {
  [Uint8Contents]: <02 00 00 00 9b 02 00 00 c0 06 00 00>,
  byteLength: 12
}
```

which has the same hex as I put in, so it seems to be working fine,
then to make the array buffer into a string I did this.

```js
let dataView = new DataView(buffer);
let decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');
let string =  decoder.decode(dataView)
```

just to test that it worked, I saved it to a file.

```js
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/test.txt', string)
```

Opening test.txt in a hex editor shows different data:
`02000000EFBFBD020000EFBFBD060000`

If I instead do

```js
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/test.txt', hexToBuffer("020000009B020000C0060000"))
```

then I get the correct data- but then if I read the file with fs and then add to it it's once again not the same values.

```js
let test = fs.readFileSync(__dirname+'/test.txt', 'utf8)
let example2 = test+'example'
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname+'/test.txt', example2)
```

now test.txt begins with `02000000EFBFBD020000EFBFBD060000` instead of `020000009B020000C0060000`. What do I do?

Comment: You shouldn't turn it into a string, just save the buffer to the file as-is. But, you can't "add to it" in the way you did because you specified to decode it as utf8... Which will change it because it isn't really utf8. Instead, work only with buffers and never convert them to a string.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you can use the [`Buffer.from(string[, encoding])`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_static_method_buffer_from_string_encoding) method to create a Buffer from a string whilst also specifying the encoding - in your case it will be `"hex"`:

```
const b1 = Buffer.from("020000009B020000C0060000", "hex")
```

Now save it to a file:

```
fs.writeFileSync(path.resolve('./test'), b1)
```

Then we can check that the file contains the same hex values as in the string by using `xxd` on the command line:

```
$ xxd test
0200 0000 9b02 0000 c006 0000
```

Looking good!

Now we can read the file back into a buffer as well, making sure to tell it the encoding of the file is `"hex"` again:

```
const b2 = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve("./test"), "hex")
```

Finally, turn it back into a string again with the Buffer.toString() method:

```
console.log(b2.toString()) // => "020000009b020000c0060000"
```